# Laravel: no joy after MAMP upgrade from 3.4 to 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

As I am suffering a weird redirect problem and I read MAMP could be the cause I decided to upgrade it.
I have my virtual hosts set and they are enabled in the conf.
I set correct ports and set PHP version to 5.6.31 (it was 5.6.10).
What happens when I start the servers is I can open the welcome screen of the laravel project (project.dev) but then the routes don't work with error 404. Example `project.dev/home` or `project.dev/login` etc.
Any clue?

--- edit

I added this to my vhost and now it's working. Not sure if all the stuff there is needed as I just copied from the web. Strangely I didn't have anything of this in the past and it worked. Could it be apache was configured to allow mod_rewrite or something?

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I guess your `.htaccess` rewrite rules are not respected.

Comment: Have you uncommented vhost conf file in your `httpd.conf`? `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Yes I did, infact the host is reached but the routes don't work

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: i strongnly sugest to give a try laravel/valet

Comment: where do I set AllowOverride All ? in vhosts?

Comment: In your `httpd.conf` file. I think by default it is `<Directory /> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None </Directory>` (excuse formatting). Did the installer leave the old MAMP folder? If so you could compare the both versions of `httpd.conf`

Comment: ok thanks I'll check che conf however I added that to vhost and now it's working. Check the edited question.

Comment: I've added the answer and an explanation as to why it may have worked previously without making the change.

Comment: @Chriz74 please mark my question as accepted - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `httpd.conf` file set [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive from None to All, for example:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The default in Apache 2.3.9 and later is None, previous versions is was All. From the [online docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride):

> When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to
>   None, .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server
>   will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
>
> When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the
>   .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files.